# Python: pause function but not whole program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sleep

I have two function, which generate random integer, and sleep for the given interval. However, I would like to sleep those two functions independently, while `time.sleep()` pauses the whole Python program.

```
def fun1():
 interval1 = random.randint(2,800)
 time.sleep(interval1)
 # do other things

def fun2():
 interval2 = random.randint(1, 999)
 time.sleep(interval2)
 # do other things, different than in fun2
```

How I can sleep a given function, such that when `fun1` is paused, `fun2` still is doing their thing as long as the `time.sleep(interval2)` is not called?

Comment: Do `fun1()` or `fun2()` need to return a value?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking either for multi-threaded or asynchronous programming. Look into Python asyncio (Python 3.4+).

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @Will, no they don't need to return a value

Comment: @Ziva look for [python multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: @Ziva Did any of the answers below help? If so, consider accepting one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do like this:

```
from threading import Thread
thread1 = Thread(target=fun1)
thread2 = Thread(target=fun2)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

This will start two threads which are independent of the main thread, calling `fun1` and `fun2` respectively.

Example:

```
from threading import Thread
import random
import time

starttime = time.time()

def fun1():
    interval1 = random.randint(1,5)
    time.sleep(interval1)
    print "%d sec: Fun1" % (time.time() - starttime)

def fun2():
    interval2 = random.randint(1,5)
    time.sleep(interval2)
    print "%d sec: Fun2" % (time.time() - starttime)

thread1 = Thread(target=fun1)
thread2 = Thread(target=fun2)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

print "Still doing things!"
```

Output:

```
Still doing things!
2 sec: Fun2
4 sec: Fun1
```

As you can see, the functions are ran but the code still continues executing the print statement after the threads.

Comment: @Will They get the job done in this case though, do they not?

Comment: Depends on his workload. If we're just sleeping, absolutely, but it's the `# do stuff` part that might need a Process :) Upvoted anyway; I answered about `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @Will Indeed, agreed. Depends on the usage, both answers are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def fun1():
    interval1 = random.randint(2,800)
    time.sleep(interval1)
    # do other things

def fun2():
    interval2 = random.randint(1, 999)
    time.sleep(interval2)
    # do other things

proc1 = Process(target=fun1)
proc2 = Process(target=fun2)
proc1.start()
proc2.start()
proc1.join()
proc2.join()
```

This will start new Python processes using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) to run `fun1()` and `fun2()` in parallel. The `join()` calls will block in the main (parent) process until `proc1` and `proc2` are complete.

Unfortunately, due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module doesn't help performance much. But if your functions are mostly just waiting, `Thread`s can be appropriate.